# PyQt remove highlight selection area from QTreeWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I have a QTreeWidget and I want to remove the blue highlight area from around the Widget itself, not from the selected item (See image).

[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: `QTreeWidget` inherits from `QFrame` which has a Frame Style property which might affect this behavior. e.g. try setting it to QNoFrame and see what happens. If this behavior handled by the Window Manager though you might not have any control over it.

Comment: I think you're right!
I've moved this outside of maya now, opening a whole new set of problems, and this issue has gone. It's probably something native to maya's Qframe stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have since found a couple of ways to achieve this, depending on your setup and the desired affect.

**Set the size Policy on the tree widget**

```
tree_widget.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
```

This will stop the QTreeWidget taking focus, preventing the blue outline from appearing.

**Set the style sheet on the tree widget**

```
tree_widget.setStyleSheet("QTreeView {border: none; outline: 0;}"
```

This will completely remove the border (which turns blue).

**Bonus, remove the blue border from tree widget items**

```
tree_widget.setStyleSheet("QTreeView::item {border: none; outline: 0;}")
```